# git branching and remote master repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have  a conceptual question with regard to git branching. I have a project on which I'm about to undertake a major refactoring.

The source code is kept in a git repository, whose master is hosted with a third party cloud server. I have a local downstream clone on which I normally work (commit, then push origin master). Other developers work on the project in the same way, pushing their commits upstream as necessary.

```
[remote repository (master?)] <-- [my repository (local?)]
```

I would like to create branch under which I can commit the refactored code. All developer should be able to work on new branch in the same fashion. That is, it must exist on the master.

As I understand it, the following command would create a branch on my ***local*** repository.

```
git branch this_is_my_branch_name
git checkout this_is_my_branch_name
```

but is this branch also propagated to the remote master?

Thank you in advance for any clarification you can provide for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. Documenting it here for posterity:

```
git push origin this_is_my_new_branch_name
```

Alternately, you can create the branch on the origin repository first, then have your local repository track it.

```
git push origin origin:refs/heads/this_is_my_new_branch_name
git checkout --track -b new_feature_name origin/this_is_my_new_branch_name
```

Further information on the subject can be found here:

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html
http://www.zorched.net/2008/04/14/start-a-new-branch-on-your-remote-git-repository/